ValueError: GetLogdirSubdirectories: path exists and is not a directory, logs
I'm using Tensorboard, which is in the pytorch package, and I've generated a quadratic function value and written it into a folder called Logs, but when I type Tensorboard --logdir=logs in the terminal for visualization, it keeps saying "Valuel: Getlodysubdilcois: Path Exis, Andesnoadirektori, Logus." "May I ask you guys if you have encountered such a problem, ask for help, thank you!
my code is
from torch.utils.tensorboard import SummaryWriter

writer = SummaryWriter("./logs")

for i in range(100):
    writer.add_scalar("y=x^2", i**2, i)

writer.close()


my directory is
enter image description here
I've tried executing this command with admin privileges, I've tried quoting the path, and I've also made sure that the logs file path is accurate and that the generated log file does exist in the logs directory, but I'm still getting this error. I hope you will help me, thank you very much!

Please use the build in image function to display the image in the question.
